# How would I make a simple 'up one level' link in Kentico portal mode?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I have a simple Kentico transformation shown below. The 'a' tag is intended to send the user back up one level in the CMS site tree. I got the single dot wildcard from Kentico documentation here http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/5_5r2/devguide/index.html?wildcard_urls.htm.

```
<h1><%# Eval("ArticleTitle",true) %></h1>
<div>
<%# Eval("ArticleText") %>
</div>
<p><a href='.'>Back to list</a></p>
```

The link takes me to the correct url, but is missing .aspx from the end of the url. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you don't mind having this functionality at the top of the page you could simply use the breadcrumb web part.

Optionally, you could actually include the web part inside your transformation, and possibly restyle it to get the effect that you want.  That shouldn't be too hard if you have basic knowledge of ASP.NET markup.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that this functionality isn't supported.

I will have to write a custom transformation function where I traverse back up the tree until I get to the correct level, and build the link url myself.